# PostgreSQL difference between values with different time stamps in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, inner-join, where-clause

I'm relatively new to working with PostgreSQL and I could use some help with this.

Suppose I have a table of forecasted values (let's say temperature) are stored, which are indicated by a dump_date_time . This dump_date_time is the date_time when the values were stored in the table. The temperature forecasts are also indicated by the date_time to which the forecast corresponds. Lets say that every 6 hours a forecast is published.

Example:

At 06:00 today the temperature for tomorrow at 16:00 is published and stored in the table. Then at 12:00 today the temperature for tomorrow at 16:00 is published and also stored in the table. I now have two forecasts for the same date_time (16:00 tomorrow) which are published at two different times (06:00 and 12:00 today), indicated by the dump_date_time.

All these values are stored in the same table, with three columns: dump_date_time, date_time and value. My goal is to SELECT from this table the **difference** between the temperatures of the two forecasts. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a join:

```
select date_time, t1.value - t2.value value_diff
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 using (date_time)
where t1.dump_date = '2020-01-01 06:00:00'::timestamp
  and t2.dump_date = '2020-01-01 16:00:00'::timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
create table forecast(dump_date_time timestamptz, date_time timestamptz, value numeric)

insert into forecast values ('09/24/2020 06:00', '09/25/2020 16:00', 50), ('09/24/2020 12:00', '09/25/2020 16:00', 52);

select max(value) - min(value) from forecast where date_time = '09/25/2020 16:00';
 ?column? 
----------
        2

--Specifying dump_date_time range
select 
    max(value) - min(value) 
from 
    forecast 
where 
    date_time = '09/25/2020 16:00' 
and 
    dump_date_time <@ 
    tstzrange(current_date + interval '6 hours', 
              current_date + interval '12 hours', '[]');
 ?column? 
----------
        2
```

This is a very simple case. If you need something else you will need to provide more information.

**UPDATE**

Add example that uses timestamptz range to select `dump_date_time` in range.